# I want to filter the numbers of a array when changing the input value with a range input but when I filter on that value it go wrong

Tags: javascript, filter

I have this issue, when I want to adjust the range it all works properly to give me the numbers above 20 as example, but when I filter the range value it returns the last element of my array and I don't know why.

You see in the filter function that I use value to work with the adjusting number of the range input, but that ain't working for some reason I don't know. It only works properly if I enter a normal number

```js
{
    const numbers = [`23`,`182`,`2`,`-2`,`11`,`9`];

    const handleChangeRange = e => {
        const $range = e.currentTarget;
        const value = $range.value;
        console.log(value);
        const fileteredByMinimum = numbers.filter(number => number > value);
        console.log(fileteredByMinimum);
    }

    const init = () => {
        const $range = document.querySelector(`.range`);
        $range.addEventListener(`change`, handleChangeRange);
    }

    init();
}
```

Comment: Drop quotation marks: use _numbers_ instead of strings in `numbers` array. Those are called numbers for a reason, after all. As it stands, you compare two strings, and `'23' < '4'`.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks to help!